# problem with viewing ASCII data files in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, ascii

I have some problem viewing an ASCII file in a structured way in arcGIS. I have tried running this code but it seems problematic at least with me. I am unable to run this. I think the code needs modification. Can you please tell me the requirements to run this code... and some other help.
the link contains the file as well as the IDL source file
https://drive.google.com/?authuser=0#folders/0B8iAKVklcaMUVU5qY2NNVFBRbDQ

Comment: Rather than just post a link to full files, you should edit your question to describe in detail the errors you are getting or what is failing and include either the relevant snippet/section of the code and/or a sample of the ascii file - such as the header and first few lines of data. Also your link, for me at least, just goes to the main Google Drive 'get started' page.

Answer (score 1):

If the L3_tropo_ozone_columns_dec04.txt is the file your are trying to display then it needs to be reformatted. To display an ascii/txt file in ArcMap you need to have a 6 row header with the number of rows, number of columns, X left coordinate, Y bottom coordinate, cell resolution, and no data value. For example.

```
ncols         270
nrows         730
xllcorner     284262.586255
yllcorner     792350
cellsize      1
NODATA_value  -9999
```